# ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1 gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I'm using gitlab runner:

```
stages:
  - deployment-windows

image: ubuntu:latest

deployment-windows:
  stage: deployment-windows
  variables:
    GIT_BRANCH: demo
    PROJECT_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
    PROJECT_DIR: "${PROJECT_NAME}"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "demo"'
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
  script:
  - sshpass -p **** ssh emamian-pc@*.*.*.* "hostname && mkdir test"
```

but it shows this error:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
$ sshpass -p **** ssh emamian-pc@**** "hostname && mkdir test"
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: i guess instead of string "hostname" you have to pass actual hostname value. try if this work.

Comment: I used it: `"mkdir test"` but it doesn't work.